# jquery-timepicker desable past time

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

Im using jquery time picker i wanted to disable the past time
This is what I have currently

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({ 
            'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
            'minTime' : "11:30 am",
            'maxTime' : "02:30 pm",
            'step': '30',
            'disableTimeRanges': [['10am', '11am']]
            
        });
```

im using
https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added the github link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `minTime` setting dynamic you can determine the current time using `new Date()`. From there you need to calculate the nearest 30 minute interval (as that's the `step` you're using). A reference to the function which calculates that date can then be provided to `minDate`. Try this:

```js
let roundDate = (date = new Date(), roundToMinutes = 30) => {
  const ms = 1000 * 60 * roundToMinutes;
  return new Date(Math.ceil(date.getTime() / ms) * ms);
}

$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'h:i A',
  minTime: roundDate,
  maxTime: "02:30 pm",
  step: '30',
  disableTimeRanges: [
    ['10am', '11am']
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.13.18/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.13.18/jquery.timepicker.min.css" />
<input type="text" class="timepicker" />
```

Comment: Thanks. However the max time is getting disable.

Comment: It seems to work in the example above. What value are you using?

Comment: i wanted to disable from 2pm to 8.30 am